# How to use withCount without With laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I don't know what's the best title for my question, but basically I want to select all the group of a user then count it all.

Currently, I have

```
        $userGroups = UserView::findOrFail($userId)
                                ->groups()
                                ->get();
```

which gives me groups of the user. I could do a foreach after to count it, but was wondering if there is a direct way. I tried adding withCount() in different ways, but didn't manage to make it work.

I could make it work with something like this, but it also gives the user data which I don't need. I only need the groups of the user. This is the reason why the title of the question is like that.

```
            $userGroups = UserView::with([
                'groups'
            ])
            ->withCount('groups AS groupCount')
            ->findOrFail($userId);
```

Comment: The [count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) method is what you're looking for, have you tried that? The `withCount` method is used for counting relationships you haven't retrieved. `UserView:findOrFail($userId)->groups()->count();` will count the result of your query.

Comment: That gives me the number only. I want all the groups, then the count afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count` on a collection too, just `$userGroups->count()` after you run your query.